# How to wild-card search/replace in a Specific Area of code in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, wildcards

again, I need to automate some content prepping of enormous docs.

Here's the sample of what I have:

```
<style tag>
Name     Description                          Name
------   --------------------------------     -------
XXXXXX   ABC QWERTY BROWN FOX                 YYYYYYY
XXXXXX   ABC QWERTY BROWN RABBIT              AAAAAAA
XXXXXX   ABC QWERTY BROWN DOG                 BBBBBBB
</style tag>
```

My two problems are: 
- I need to insert `&nbsp;` to replace every blank (space) just in the Style Tag Area.
- I need to put `<p>` and `</p>` at the begining and end of each line in the Style Tab area.

I hope you'll forgive both my naivety (aka lack of skills) and desparation when I tell you there are several hundreds of these Style Tag areas in every doc I need to process. And there are several hundreds docs....

Thanks :)

Kris

Comment: @FrankSixteen

FYI, I spent about 24 hours of searching for and trying multiple methods. None of them works for me in THIS scenario. 

Hence my lack of skills line. Which happens to be the reason why I came to ask the pros.

There are not THOUSANDS of ways of doing this but there are thousands of ways of saying it without ridiculing people who lack YOUR set of skills. Maybe an emergency paramedic will give you an 'Anatomy for the begineers' the next time you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching **In Selection**?

[image]

yields

[image]